# Get values from single json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is the json returning from controller through ajax

```
[{"UserID":"1","Username":"admin","Password":"#######","FullName":"Hassan","Email":"admin@admin.com","Phone":null,"Mobile":null,"PreviousAddress":null,"CNIC":null,"theme":null,"GroupID":"1"}]
```

i want to get values from the array.

I tried like this

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data.UserID);
}
```

but i get `undefined` in the console.

Comment: `data` is an array. Elements should be accessed as `data[i].UserId`,  and so on. Also, make sure you are sending `content-type: text/json` header along with the response!

Comment: You should mention that you are using $.getJSON (if you do)

Comment: @DOCASAREL: looks pretty much like JSON to me.

Comment: The console says it is an object %)P @FelixKling

Comment: @DOCASAREL: Sure, if you evaluate the text `[{"UserID":"1", ...}]` in a JavaScript context (like the console), it will evaluate to an array containing an object. That's no surprise since the JSON syntax is a subset of JavaScript's object literal syntax. However, if `[{"UserID":"1", ...}]` is the whole response from the server, then yes, it is JSON.

Comment: Exactly that's where I am flipping right now @FelixKling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access the first index of the array

```
console.log(data[0].UserID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set dataType to json in ajax call. The result will be parsed and returned as an object in your success result.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "yourscript.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: your data,
  dataType: "json"
}).
success(function (data) {
...
});
```

Comment: how do u do that? :p

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript `[]` means `array` therefore your Object it is actually an array of objects `[{"UserID":"1",...},{"UserID":"2",...}, etc]`

In order to access each object you will need to loop trough or use the index number you want  to access like `var obj =[{"UserID":"1",...` then `obj[0].UserID`